# Вызов LogonUserA из NodeJS используя ffi

Tags: node.js, ref, ffi

Мне нужно выполнить функцию LogonUserA из библиотеки Advapi32.dll (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera) используя ffi на NodeJS.

Cама загрузка библиотеки и инициализация функции:

```
var ffi = require('ffi');
var ref = require('ref');
var Advapi32 = new ffi.Library ('Advapi32', {
    LogonUserA: ['bool', ['string', 'string', 'string', 'ulong', 'ulong', 'pointer']]
});
module.exports = {
    Advapi32: Advapi32
  };
```

Ну и собственно вызов

```
const platform = require('./lib/win32.js');
let logon = platform.Advapi32.LogonUserA('name', 'domain', 'test123', 0, 0, НЕЧТО_ТИПА_PHANDLE)
```

Так вот, собственно сам вопрос, я ранее не сталкивался с задачами использования ffi и напрямую не стучался из ноды в функцию из спп библиотеки, и совершенно не могу понять, каким образом правильно задать последний, пятый аргумент. 
По примеру из майкрософт докс, это должен быть указазатель на переменную дескрптора "&hToken". Не могу взять в толк, каким образом завести удовлетворяющую переменную в nodeJs?
Я пробовал по разному, использовал типы ref, но результат может быть либо никаким (процесс просто прерывается) либо выдавать ошибку:

```
error setting argument 5 - writePointer: Buffer instance expected as third argument
```

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался сам. Последний аргумент должен был быть буфером.